# Discrete math proof methods: Does $m\mid a\cdot b\cdot c$ imply $m\mid a$ or $m\mid b$ or $m\mid c$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I have some question in proof methods, it looks very easy to answer it but i don't know how to explain it..
The question is:

$a,b,c∈ℕ$, and $1 < m ∈\mathbb N$

if $m\mid a\cdot b\cdot c$ (P) prove or disprove that $m\mid a$ or $m\mid b$ or $m\mid c$ (Q)**

Which proof method should I use here? (direct, contrapositive, etc..)

Thanks...

Comment: It's false. For example a=b=c=2 and m=4.

Comment: wow you're right i didn't think about it...but i didn't understnad how to disprove it

Comment: If $m$ is prime  , then this true . If $m$ is composite , then it is not necessarily true. $\text{ Try using Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic .}$

Comment: A counterexample suffices to disprove

Comment: if i use counterexample, how can i write (mathematically) for example that x is not divide in n? because if x divide in n i can write x = n*k

Comment: \$4 \nmid 2\$ produces $4\nmid2$, which means $4$ does not divide $2$

Comment: there is a way to disprove it without giving a specific example? i mean in more general way..

Comment: In general, a specific counterexample is a fine disproof.  Here it might be more enlightening to talk of some prime $p$, which can divide $m$ multiple times and each of $a,b,c$ too few times.

Comment: A general counterexample : take $\ 3\ $ integers $\ a,b,c>1\ $ and choose $\ m=abc\ $